# how to prevent creating a new instance of a component when they need to be rearranged?

Tags: java, html, css, reactjs

So on the desktop version, the component looks like this:

```
  <div className="parent-comp">
    <div id="child-1" />
    <div id="child-2" />
  </div>
```

But on the mobile version, things flip:

```
  <div className="parent-comp">
    <div id="child-2" />
    <div id="child-1" />
  </div>
```

How to prevent having to recreate `child-1` and `child-2` when the screen size changes from mobile to desktop, etc?

Comment: You could use pure CSS `flex` for the parent  and `order` for the inner divs.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a state to store idNum and implement a function that detects screen size and set proper idNum
Below is a try i hope will solve that problem:

```
const [idNum, setIdNum] = useState(1);
    const handleResize = () => {
        if (window.innerWidth > 960) {
            setIdNum(1);
        } else {
            setIdNum(2);
        }
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        handleResize();
    });
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    return (
        <div className="parent-comp">
            <div id={`child-${idNum}`} />
            <div id={`child-${idNum === 1 ? 2 : 1}`} />
        </div>
    );
```